# ¿Por que no me funciona el get de una function en poo php?

Tags: php, html, poo, get

Buenas hice una clase numero y quiero retornar su valor pero me devuelve 0, no se que estaria haciendo mal

```
<?php
 class Numero{

private $num;

 public function __constructor($num){

$this->num=$num;

}

public function getNumero(){
return $this->num;
}

  }

 ?>
```

```
   <?php
   include_once"numero.php";

    $n4=(new Numero(4))->getNum();

    echo $n4;

   ?>
```

Comment: en lugar de editar la pregunta para poner el código sin el error, deberías aceptar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Comment: tenes razon, disculpa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas haciendo `getNum()` en lugar de `getNumero()`

Comment: ya lo arregle y da lo mismo

Comment: gracias :D era eso no me habia dado cuenta jajaj